# anorm joda-time - localdatetime support

Tags: scala, jodatime, anorm

With Anorm 2.5.2

```
SQL(s"insert into user (name, registered_date) values ({name},{registered_date})").on(
  'name -> user.name,
  'registered_date -> user.registeredDate
).executeInsert()
```

Compilation error:

> Error:(72, 24) type mismatch;  found   : (Symbol,
>   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime)  required: anorm.NamedParameter
>         'registered_date -> user.registeredDate

Should I include some implicit Time->Row transformation or it should come out of the box with anorm?

where user:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long] = None,
                name: String,
                registeredDate: LocalDateTime // joda-time'
               )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   import anorm.JodaParameterMetaData._
```

from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/I6TnTzO5MUw

(it was nice talking to myself :) )